# bwmorph(image, ‘skel’, inf) and edge(image, ‘log’, 0, 2) in matlab with same result in python

Tags: matlab, python, image-processing

What are example of two functions in python with this result?

bwmorph(image, ‘skel’, inf)

and

edge(image, ‘log’, 0, 2)

in matlab with same result in python?

My problem is that result in python not equal with matlab

I want that will be equal python result with matlab

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: I suggest you to propose the question in stack-overflow!